# Is my ISP throttling my internet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, isp

So I have had issues for my internet this past month. It randomly disconnects and Windows says the default gateway is not available when I run the diagnostics. After some time it clears up and I am able to continue surfing. But I have been able to isolate the cause: This happens only when I download large files at maximum speed, like 40 GB file via Steam. After a while, those crashes become frequent, with gateway being available and unavailable intermittently. But when I pause the download and let it sit for few minutes no internet disconnection happens for a long time, if I use the internet "casualy" (email, youtube, news etc, no heavy load). And I noticed it happens mostly through day, at night I can download to my heart content.

Should I contact my ISP to explain themselves why they purposely gimp my internet connection? It is "no monthly download limit" plan, so they have no reason to throttle me.

Comment: If you were being throttled by your ISP, it would be slower, but it shouldn't cause disconnects.

Comment: As an aside, "unlimited bandwidth usage" does not mean "unlimited service." ISPs tend to dislike a small subset of their customers using up most of the network resources, degrading the service for the rest of their customers. They will throttle the speed of high-usage users, usually after a certain cap is reached, or during certain hours of the day. But as @TTT stated, this is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment saying that throttling should cause slow-down,
not disconnects.

My opinion is that this is most probably caused by the ISP having over-committed
the lines, thus causing you timeouts.
Apparently there are heavy day-users in your area.

Try to change the settings in your download program(s) to allow for longer timeout
values.