# What is my ISP doing to my internet, Extremely slow internet and ...?

Tags: networking, internet, isp, throttling

My usually 8 Mbps home connection has been extremely slow for the past few days, with *all* pages I visit taking much longer than usual, some taking more than 30 or 50 seconds to load. and the online test speed show below 100k or sometimes 10k and don't connecting !!!

## The setup

I have a single device acting as ADSL modem and i closed all other connection so i tested by one user connection to modem the the results are like this:
[image]

- Everything is using DHCP, no client has fixed IP.
- PPPoE is configured on the modem and all clients are always on, no authentication needed. It's always been like this
- There's no proxy, firewall, VPN, tunnel or anything like that.

## Preliminary diagnostics

but after complaining to ISP and trithing them to post in the internet about no answering to costumers an one week delay, playing with costumer and .. the speed now changed to 1Mbps based of some sites like **www.speedtest.net**  the modem setting is accessible [here](https://www.speedtest.net/result/8996681230) and shown below:

[image]

and for susa telcom server test [here](https://www.speedtest.net/result/8996693007):
[image]

and :

[image]

so  now the modem statistics is like this:

[image]

## What have I done

- Rebooted the router
- Positioned the laptop 30cm from the router
- Switched from WiFi to wired Ethernet
- Booted into a fresh Live USB Ubuntu install
- Changed the wifi password and made sure I was the only active client
- Changed DNS servers to [first' `172.28.195.35` and second `8.8.8.8`](
- telephoning to ISP, threatening  to posting via internet about them and complaining

So i sensing they are not clear and sometimes by changing the bandwidth of user are playing by costumers,but i am not professional in this the networking and ADSL modem setting so asked here to know what they are doing to costumers like me and what test needed to clarify what is going now?

After seeing [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1155787/is-my-isp-throttling-my-internet-connection) i think, if they want to throttling my bandwidth, could them do this any time or by some scripts to doing this automatically and this could be one candidate source of happening this situation?

Comment: "usually 8 Mbps " It is still 8mbps on all your tests. It even goes up to 10mbps? ADSL is very unstable. I suggest you check for any phone line that is damaged or used by a phone.

Comment: There are no more choice for my only can change ADSL ISP provider

Comment: Noise on the telephone line can do this, you will have to contact the phone company for them to do a diagnosis, not the isp. Been there done that.